# New account validation

Tags: support, login

I created a new account an closed the validation page by mistake before I could put in the validation code i was e mailed. How do I get that page back up to validate my account? I have tried to go through the account set up again an it says Email already in use, but wont let me log in.

Comment: This has been migrated to the meta site based on the assumption that the kind of *account* you're talking about is an online account for Ask Ubuntu. If that is not the case, please let us know. The more information you can provide, the more likely you'll get a good answer. You can *edit* your question to add new information. I think that there *might* be a link in the email you received, which you may be able to click to validate your account.